# Facebook LoginButton doesn't work, just show a spinning screen

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm following Facebook [instruction](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.4) and use their own LoginButton, I ran into 2 issues (they happened randomly between the two) :

- It said invalid hash key, although I've added the key to the FB app **or**
- There's a spinner, but then nothing else happened. In this case, I checked `onActivityResult` function, got the following:
  requestCode = 129742
  resultCode = -1

Also in both cases, in the following function of FacebookButtonBase, `externalOnClickListener` is null

```
protected void callExternalOnClickListener(final View v) {
        if (externalOnClickListener != null) {
            externalOnClickListener.onClick(v);
        }
    }
```

What am I missing? Thanks

**Update:** the way I obtained the key hash is using this provided piece of code and copy the value out, paste onto FB.

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     try {
         PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                           "com.facebook.samples.loginhowto", 
                            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
         for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                  }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

          }
            ...
```

Comment: Did you use the code given over [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.4#keyhash)?

Comment: You mean the code to get the key hash, not the key hash generated from keytool, right? Yes, I did obtain the key hash that way

Comment: Yes, the code to write in the application create and then using that key hash in facebook. Did you try that out?

Comment: Yes, I did, just update my question.

Comment: Well, ideally the above should work. My suggestion is to create a fresh dummy project with just FB Login and try again. Make sure to use the above code to generate the key hash and not the keytool. (Keytool gives problems most of the time)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this to your AndroidManifest ?

```
<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```